# Empathy not connecting on school's public wifi

Tags: 11.04, empathy, proxy

Empathy just sits trying to connect to my facebook and Google Talk accounts on my school's public wifi.

On the public wifi there is a proxy I have to connect to and register with (just type in an email address) and I can browse the web. Services like Ubuntu One, Apt, and others work fine. I've only found Irssi and Empathy unable to connect. Google talk via Gmail works fine too.

I feel this is a network-port issue, but I don't know how to resolve it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a proxy there on the school network? empathy doesn't work behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Applications that don't use the system proxy settings. The only thing you can do is wait for this feature to be added in the programs that don't work.

It could also be, that sites like chat.facebook.com are blocked in the schools network so empathy can not connect to them. At my school, it is like that and I can only use the chat through the websites with https.